# RHEL6 BIND9 XML Statistics-channels build library modification after server is already up and running

Tags: rhel, linux-kernel, bind, bind9

Migrating away from BIND9 to Route53 and would prefer not to use the `named.stats` file for monitoring activity during the migration period. As such, I checked the current `named.conf` and verified no `statistics-channels` entry exists, so no http web page for monitoring using xml channel.

My question is, since the previous sysadmins that deployed these BIND servers (RHEL 6) did not build it using `./configure --with-libxml2` based on my checks here:

```
[root@XXXXX /]# ldconfig -p | grep libxml2
        libxml2.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libxml2.so.2
[root@XXXXX /]# ldconfig -p | grep libxml2-dev
[root@XXXXX /]# named -v
BIND 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.68.rc1.el6_10.11
[root@XXXXX /]#
```

I see that libxml2 is on the system, however, it does not show up in the output of `named -v` as is documented in `kb.isc.org`:

```
If you are having trouble getting the statistics server to function, check the output of named -V to ensure that BIND was configured with libxml2, e.g.:

$ named -V
BIND 9.9.1-P2 built with '--prefix=/usr/local/bind-9.9.1-P2' '--with-libxml2'
```

Another observation is that `libxml2-dev` is not on the system, not explicitly required for all installs, just on some systems.

So, does anyone know if can I modify the BIND software build AFTER initial configuration in order to get http monitoring of statistics (i.e.; Install the libxml2-dev library and supposedly get the libxml2-dev package loaded into the BIND configuration) or would I have to do a completely new build to enable this functionality instead of having to rely on monitoring the statistics file?